# Updating and editing Google Sheet on Form submission

Tags: google-sheets-api

Here is basically what I am looking to do. I have a form with an entry date, an activity, and a field called active. I want to write a script that looks for specific variables and if it sees the matching variables changes the active field to discontinued and enters the new exit date from the form submission. Finally it will delete the new entry that called for the exit date so that there is only one entry in the Sheet that has both the entry and exit and now instead of saying active it says discontinued. My logic is as follows:

Form submission Sub1:
Student last name 2,
Student first name 3,
Intervention 4,
Active 5,
entry date

Form submission Sub2:
Student last name 2,
Student first name 3,
Intervention 4,
Discontinued 5,
Exit date

If (5 == Discontinued), then find where Sub2(2 && 3 && 4) == Sub1(2 && 3 && 4) and where 5 == Active and change it to Discontinued and add exit date
then delete sub2

Comment: You've explained what you want to do, but in what way can we help?

Comment: I just need help writing the if statement.